# Getting started with jQuery

Tags: jquery

What is a good place to start playing with jQuery, besides the jQuery website. I'm having trouble with the way the site is set up - I dislike it.

Comment: You could always just download it and try it out on your local browser. And you'll get used to the jQuery documentation...or I guess you could rewrite the documentation somewhere else in a format of your choice if you really want?

Comment: @Shhnap - lol. Don't tempt me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another site, dedicated to jQuery, I found very useful for me - [visualjquery.com](http://visualjquery.com/).
One of the creators of this site is also author of the great book "jQuery in Action"(Yehuda Katz).

As for me, resource is well orginized and extremely handy.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. Nice link.

Answer (score 4):

There is a list of [tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) on the jQuery site.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a few resources, both by members of the jQuery core team:

1. [Learning jQuery Website](http://www.learningjquery.com/)
2. [jQuery Enlightenment](http://jqueryenlightenment.com/) e-book ($15 at time of writing)

***Disclaimer:*** I was provided a free copy of jQuery Enlightenment to review. I personally feel it is well worth the $15, and the code samples in the book are plenteous and very clear.

Comment: @Moshe, haha. Well, I couldn't say it was worth $15 if I paid nothing, so I added the disclaimer :) We will probably run a giveaway on http://fuelyourcoding.com when I post the review, so maybe you can try your luck then!

Comment: Thanks for the tipoff about the site and the giveaway. Another "gotoonsystemtartup" website. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Official document is not always that easy to grasp. I found this to be extremely useful resource for learning jquery:

http://15daysofjquery.com/

Comment: Agreed, it isn't - hence the question. Interesting link.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very good book [jQuery in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355) 
After reading the book, read jQuery source code.

Comment: It seems that a few people here like this book.
Thank you for recommending it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to learn it is go through the tutorials and actually write the code from scratch, don't just read them.  Also look at some problems you want to solve using jQuery and try a few different approaches to solving them to find all the different ways it allows you to work.  jQuery is very rich and there's more than one way to skin your site...I mean cat.

Comment: Interesting points. 
1)I generally learn by writing code. There is a middle road to your suggestion though - modifying other people's code.
2)Solving problems in multiple ways... I like to learn on the job, but if it aint broke, I aint gonna fix it. 
3)jQuery is rich -  but I don't quite get the rest of your remarks...
Thanks for the answer!